How to change from dark to light theme in frama-c GUI
I want to change to light mode in the frama-c GUI, which opens in dark mode.
Thought it could be done by writing
frama-c-gui -gui-theme as indicated in this tutorial but I get the following error:
[kernel] User Error: option `-gui-theme' is unknown.

Am I doing something wrong?

You can use theGTK_THEME variable. For example:
GTK_THEME=Yaru frama-c-gui

